# How to access the window size of a frame with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

In python selenium I am selecting an iframe via

```
frame = driver.find_element(*locator)
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

and then later I am trying to access the size of that iframe. I tried the following:

```
frame.get_window_rect()
frame.get_window_size()
frame.contentWindow.get_window_rect()
frame.contentWindow.get_window_size()
```

but it looks like the element 'frame' neither has an attribute 'get_window_rect`, nor 'get_window_size`, nor `contentWindow`. So how to access the size of the iframe element/window/rectangle/whatever?

I need that information **after** I have switched to the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

`get_window_rect()` and `get_window_size()` are webdriver methods. Webelements have `rect` and `size` properties

```
frame = driver.find_element(*locator)
rect = frame.rect # {'height': 888, 'width': 912}
```

Note that you can't use the `frame` element after switching to it, it's not in the driver context any longer it will throw `StaleElementReferenceException`.

To get the `<iframe>` size after switching to it you can use the `<html>` tag

```
rect = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').rect
```

Comment: So how to get the size of the iframe AFTER having switched to it?

Comment: @Alex You can get the `html` tag size under the frame, it should be the same.

Comment: and how exactly to do this? Can you provide a code snippet for that please?

Comment: Thanks, now I get some values, but these are the wrong values: `{'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'width': 1563.0, 'height': 0.0}` The height of the iframe is not 0 pixels - more like 8000 pixels. I tried also with `size`, but here I also get a 'height' of 0!

Comment: @Alex Did you try it on the frame or the html tag? you can get the values from the frame before the switch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201017/discussion-between-alex-and-guy).